# Run .EXE without Qt

Tags: qt, compiler-construction

**[ [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022967/run-my-application-created-using-qt-without-qt/#16026526) ]**

I want to run my app created with `QtSDK` on a machine that does not have `Qt` installed.

I tried to copy the `DLL's` from the `BIN` folder to the release of my project, but it did not work.

### I tried the following:

- I copy all `dll's` folder `d:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin`
- And pasted it in the folder of my project: `d:\projects\mybrowser\mybrowser-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release`
- and send it to another computer `without Qt`
- In computer `without Qt`, I installed `vcredist_sp1_x86.exe` and tried to run my application `browsertest.exe`

### The following error occurred:

> microsoft visual c++ runtime library: this application has requested
>   the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

**Q: What I really want to know:**

How do I run an application built in Qt on other computers (Windows) without Qt installed?

### Details:

- Qt5.0.1 32bit
- mingw 4.7 32bit
- QtCreator 2.6.2
- Windows 7 64bit.
- Intel i5

**Folders:**

- D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32
- D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW

**Qt/Mingw:**

- D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin\qmake.exe
- d:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe

---

File **.pro**:

```
QT += webkitwidgets network core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = browsertest
TEMPLATE = app

RC_FILE = browser.rc

SOURCES += main.cpp\
 mybrowser.cpp

HEADERS += mybrowser.h

FORMS += mybrowser.ui
```

If any information you missed, please let me know.
grateful

Comment: If targeted PC was missing any DLLs, error message would've said so explicitly… Now it looks like there is a bug in your code (check out Details Section in that error dialog).

Comment: I created an application (QMainWindow) simple
and the same error occurs. I edited my question, I await your return. Thanks.

Comment: mingw, visual studio? It's either mingw OR visual studio, how come you need both?

Comment: You'll also need DLL's from the `D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Lib` and `D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\plugins` directory. I usually use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find missing dependencies.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing compilers or Release and Debug in the same application. What I mean is do not build dlls with 1 compiler and executables with a different compiler, different versions of the compiler or some parts Release while other parts Debug. These are all recipes for crashes due to incompatible CRT. Most important is different and incompatible heaps. You can not allocate memory in a debug heap and release it in a release heap.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To distribute your application you need to copy the **DLLs** (only the **DLLs** necessary).

1. Copy the **DLLs** necessary from
   `<DRIVE>:\Qt\Qt<Version_qt>\<Version_qt>\mingw<Version_mingw>\` or `<DRIVE>:\Qt\Qt<Version_qt>\<Version_qt>\mingw<Version_mingw>\bin\`

   **eg.:** `C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\` or `C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\bin`
2. Paste the folder of your application.
3. Then copy the folders inside of `<DRIVE>:\Qt\Qt<Version_qt>\<Version_qt>\mingw<Version_mingw>\plugins`

   **eg.:** `C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\plugins`
4. Paste the folders of your application.

> Note: In this example (below), it was necessary to copy DLLs from different places and remove the **Debug DLLs** (used only to compile in **Debug**).
>
> Note that the `debug dlls` end with "d.dll", for example: *Qt5Core.dll* and *Qt5Cored.dll* or *Qt5Concurrent.dll* and *Qt5Concurrentd.dll*, the ending with "d.dll" should not be copied.

The structure should look something like this (example):

- c:\project\app.exe (your app created in **Qt**)
- c:\project\Qt5Core.dll (**dll** from **qt/mingw** folder or **qt/mingw/bin**)
- c:\project\platforms (**folder** from **qt/mingw/plugins** folder)
- c:\project\platforms\qminimal.dll (**dll** from **qt/mingw/plugins/platforms** folder)

Only some **DLLs** the **mingw** will be needed, so I recommend using the [Dependency Walker 2.2](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

The result should look like this (not all dlls are needed, this can vary by project type):
[image: app folder]

---

Thanks to:

- +1 for @MartinBeckett, showed me the program to find the **DLLs** required.
- +1 for @WouterHuysentruit, thanks to the application I indicated, I discovered that the contents of the **mingw\plugins** folder should go straight into the application folder.
- @WouterHuysentruit I would consider your answer as correct, but you just said, so I put a simpler explanation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you for being the first search result I've found that clearly specifies where the DLLs needed come from!

Answer (score 2):

"microsoft visual c++ runtime library: this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"

That's either an ordinary bug, or sometimes a mix of incompatible dlls
Use the (free) [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) program on your exe to check which dlls it actually uses - it probably isn't linking all of Qt

Some Qt libs are loaded at runtime from a plugins folder, mostly image formats and database connections - but they woudln't give this error

Comment: I managed to fix the dlls,
but still have this error: `Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.`. It seems that the problem is in the dll `ieframe.dll`, I tried using the `Dependency Walker` to `ieframe.dll`
but the same error occurred. What could it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

windeployqt (delivered with QT 5.2+) should do (most?) of the work