# Run my application without Qt on linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I wrote an application in Qt5 on Linux. How can I run this app on another Linux without using Qt and compile project again. I found this question: [Run .EXE without Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022967/run-my-application-created-using-qt-without-qt) But it is related to Windows. I want to do that on Linux.

Comment: Qt runtimes come installed on virtually every distro, and is available on every distro's package repos.  So why do you want to do this on Linux!?

Comment: I use a changed Linux distro. It has no Qt libraries. And I am trying to run Qt5 without installling Qt5. Or I should install only necessary libraries.

Comment: Be aware that Qt's licensing differs between dynamic and static linking. Because of this not all Qt modules support static linking.

Comment: Using static libs is not the only way, and is difficult if application is not GPL, so marked duplicateis, at best, partial solution for some subset of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically the same, however, for Linux:

- Basic instructtion for static link:
  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-x11.html
- Some note on deploying for Linux and licensing:
  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment.html
- If you need plug-ins:
  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html