# How Do I Make My Qt Project Static (.exe)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I made a test program in Qt to see if I liked it.  So one of my friends asked if he could see the program, so I built the project as Release, and it saved it in

```
build-wordX1-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Qt 5.1.0 MinGW 32bit Release \ Release
```

I don't know why, but when I open the executable I get this

[image: Error Message]

I got it to work with another program, but I had to include 1 folder and 15 DLLs
Here's the list of DLLs I had to include: http://pastebin.com/7AHNWaDE

If anyone can help, I'd be so grateful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that distributing a program that is statically linked to Qt libraries legally requires you to purchase a commercial license, unless your own program is also distributed under the LGPL. A commercial license is not cheap, so unless you have deep pockets the _right_ _way_ to this is typically to bundle the DLLs with your application.

Comment: @Slavik81 - ironically, Qt for android produces a single APK, surely it contains all the packages, but it is neat to get it as one file, and without being an actual installer - apk's are just zip files.

Comment: Maybe this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022967/run-exe-without-qt helps you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite a difficult task you attempt. You need the static libs for Qt. Problem is, I am not aware of a location where you can download it. So you have to compile it yourself. 
You need to download the sources and configure for static build:

configure -opensource -release **-static** -nomake examples -nomake demos

-nomake examples -nomake demos saves you time.

This gives you the static version of all Qt libs. They are ending in .a .

In the .pro file of your program you have to add:
CONFIG += static

The rest is praying. Most likely it will fail with some obscure error message. The net is full with reports of people, who have problems with static Qt builds. Additionally due to license reasons it is not easy to release a statically linked Qt program. Your program gets huge. You don't save any disk space. And your program gets inflexible. No easy replacement of Qt libs should Digia fix some bugs. With very few exceptions, one is the qt installer framework, I'd say: Don't bother with static Qt.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I was really looking forward to using Qt for my projects, but I guess not...thanks for your answer, I tried the CONFIG += static, but it didn't work still.  I guess I'll just learn the Windows API -__________-

Comment: Are the dynamic libs really a problem? When you use static libs, they are just 'hidden' in your binary. The are still there and take space. Not much different as when you put them into your installation folder. You said MinGW, so you are developing under Windows, which means you need an installer anyways. The installer could easily handle the installation and deinstallation of your Qt libs. For a user of your program it does not make much of a difference, if he has one 100mb program, or one 10mb program and 90mb in various dlls.

Comment: @Greenflow That's not true. Statically linking excludes all code that is not needed. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)

Comment: And how much of Qt do you think you don't need? From your Wikipedia link: In static linking, the size of the executable becomes greater than in dynamic linking, as the library code is stored within the executable rather than in separate files. **But if library files are counted as part of the application then the total size will be similar.**

Comment: Good news guys...I switched to C# :D I think this is going to be better for me in the long run.